# How to animate ionic page/modal to slide in from right

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, angular5, cordova-plugins

I did some research and what I saw is this:

A cordova plugin to get native page transitions but this is only on mobile.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions/

If I want to make this work on mobile app and web what is the best option to follow here?

What I want to do is to slide my page and modal from right to the position of the page/modal.

Is this achievable by just using css animations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the ionic config to achieve this:

```
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
       modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
       modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
       pageTransition: 'ios-transition'
      }
    }, {}
  )],
  ...
})
```

see https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/ for reference.

For single Page transitions you can use:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  openModal() {
    const modal = this.modalCtrl.create('ContactPage', {}, { enterAnimation: 'modal-slide-in', leaveAnimation: 'modal-slide-out' });
    modal.present();
  }

  openPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push('ContactPage', {}, { animation: 'ios-transition' });
  }

}
```

Note: There is no built-in modal transition to slide in from the right but you can define it yourself like described in this forum post:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/adding-custom-transitions-custom-modal-transition/75924/3

Comment: Could you also show me how I specify the animation for a specific page/ modal?

Comment: Do I have to set the config options in the IonicPageModule.forChild(page, config here)?

Comment: The config should be set in your root app module. I updated my answer for the single page transitions.

Answer (score 4):

In app.module.ts, import this:

```
import { iosTransitionAnimation } from '@ionic/core/dist/collection/utils/transition/ios.transition';
```

After that, add like this:

```
imports: [
    ...
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot({
        navAnimation:iosTransitionAnimation
    }),
    ...
],
```

It works in Ionic 4.

Maybe it helps someone!

Comment: Since Ionic 5, the import is now `import { iosTransitionAnimation } from '@ionic/core';`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ionic 6, then you can use

```
enterAnimation = (baseEl: HTMLElement) => {
const root = baseEl.shadowRoot;
const backdropAnimation = this.animationCtrl
  .create()
  .addElement(root.querySelector('ion-backdrop')!)
  .fromTo('opacity', '0.01', 'var(--backdrop-opacity)');

  const wrapperAnimation = this.animationCtrl
  .create()
  .addElement(root.querySelector('.modal-wrapper')!)
  .keyframes([
    { offset: 0, opacity: '0', transform: 'translateX(-100%)' },
    { offset: 1, opacity: '0.99', transform: 'translateX(0)' },
  ]);

return this.animationCtrl
  .create()
  .addElement(baseEl)
  .easing('ease-out')
  .duration(500)
  .addAnimation([backdropAnimation, wrapperAnimation]);


 };

  leaveAnimation = (baseEl: HTMLElement) => {
    return this.enterAnimation(baseEl).direction('reverse');
  };
```